# Algorithm for matching object properties with rules

Tags: c#, algorithm, haskell

Apologies for the unclear title. Here's the explanation:

I have a type of object Foo having properties a,b,c,d. Lets say each of these properties(type of string/bool) can have individually 3 unique value (a has 1,2,3; b has 11,12,13 and so on).

I have a set of rules against which I want to match the list of Foo objects. The rules can have one or more property with a value selected. Example:
rule 1 : a=1
rule 2 : b=12 and a=2

I wanted to know what would be the optimum way for getting the rules matched (C#/Haskell based solution would be preferable though just an explanation of algorithm is also fine).

I mention C# as I would be interested if there is any possible way we can use LINQ for these kind of matching. Haskell is mentioned as a proxy for functional language , so a recursive, branch free approach.

I am currently using a dictionary to build rules and then using reflections to get the match complete. The best thing I like about the current solution is that if we need to add a new property then its easy, plus due to less branching the code is quite easy and small to understand.

**Adding an example for greater clarity**

We have a list of animal objects with following properties

```
Object:Animal
Properties: Color, LivingEnvironment, Place, Mammal (all properties are of type string)
```

**Data:**

```
Animal1 : Red, Water, Arctic, No
Animal2 : Black, Land, Asia, No
Animal3 : Blue, Land, UK, Yes
```

**Rule**

```
Rule1 : Color=Red And LivingEnvironment=Land
Rule2 : Color=Red And LivingEnvironment=Water
Rule3 : COlor=Blue And Place=UK And Mammal=Yes
```

The rules are configurable from the user interface, so they are not known at the compile time.
Potentially a user can come along and change Rule 3 to a new definition

```
Rule3 : Color=Blue And PLace=UK
```

I hope this clarifies some of the confusion that has been caused earlier.

Comment: can you give an example of your rule? is it a string? What exactly it looks like?

Comment: I have an example of rule in the above, its kind of a key value dictionary with the key being one or more properties of foo object and value being one of the specific values the property can have.

Comment: and you have only "and" condition or have got "or" conditions as well?

Comment: A rule is a composition of smaller conditions as given in the example, The algorithm would be quite identical in case of and/or condition.

Comment: To what extent are the rules known at compile-time, and to what extent can they be specified at run-time? e.g. maybe the values to match against are read from a configuration file, but the fields that can be matched against are known by the rule-matching engine?

Answer (score 2):

A rule is just a function:

```
type Rule = Foo -> Bool
```

Here's a function to make a rule:

```
(=:=) :: Eq a => (Foo -> a) -> a -> Rule
f =:= x = \foo -> f foo == x
```

(e.g. `a =:= 1`)

Here are a couple of functions to combine rules:

```
allRules, anyRules :: [Rule] -> Rule
allRules rules foo = all ($ foo) rules
anyRule  rules foo = any ($ foo) rules
```

(e.g. `allRules [b =:= 12, a =:= 2]`)

Use the standard `filter` function to filter your `[Foo]`.

---

You want to read your rules from a configuration file. I assume that you get a list of pairs of strings from reading/parsing your config.

Let's start with a function to turn a pair of strings into a rule:

```
readRule :: String -> String -> Maybe Rule
readRule = fieldName requiredValue = do
    constructRule <- lookup fieldName ruleDefs
    constructRule requiredValue

ruleDefs :: [(String, String -> Maybe Rule)] -- should be a Map irl
```

Now let's write a helper function to generate entries in `ruleDefs`:

```
ruleEntry :: (Read a, Eq a) => String -> (Foo -> a) -> String -> Maybe Rule
ruleEntry name project = (name, constructRule) where
    constructRule requiredValue
        = case filter (null . snd) (reads requiredValue) of
            [(value, _)] -> Just (value ==)
            _            -> Nothing
```

Beyond that helper function, you could write `ruleDefs` by hand:

```
ruleDefs = [
    ruleEntry "alpha" alpha,
    ruleEntry "beta"  beta,
    ruleEntry "gamma" gamma,
    ruleEntry "delta" delta]
```

This construction works both for fields (e.g. `alpha` and `beta` in `data Foo = Foo { alpha :: Int, beta :: Int }`) and computed fields (e.g. `delta foo = alpha foo - beta foo`). I shall show a couple of techniques for building `ruleDefs` without so much repetitive typing, and they will both use Template Haskell.

(More to come.)

Comment: great rule/matching definition!, on the other hand, rules are commonly configurable, how you read from backend?

Comment: @josejuan I have a busy day of train travel, bbq, and cheesy europop ahead of me. Shall update further when I get more time and internet.

Answer (score 1):

### If you have only one rule:

What you call rules are quite simply [predicates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Predicate_%28mathematical_logic%29), or [specifications](http://martinfowler.com/apsupp/spec.pdf). I will show you two ways to filter a collection of `Foo` objects in C# according to some rule. For both examples, let's assume that we have a `Foo[] foos`:

**C# example using LINQ:**

The `Func<Foo, bool>` delegate type is suitable for predicate functions on `Foo` objects:

```
Func<Foo, bool>  someRule     = foo => foo.a == 2 && foo.b == 12;
IEnumerable<Foo> matchingFoos = foos.Where(someRule);
```

**C# example without LINQ:**

Before there were the various `Func<>` delegate types, the .NET class library already had [`Predicate<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bfcke1bz.aspx) which is appropriate here:

```
Predicate<Foo> someRule     = delegate(Foo foo) { return foo.a == 2 && foo.b == 12; };
Foo[]          matchingFoos = Array.FindAll(foos, someRule);
```

(Note that unlike the LINQ-based solution, this one returns a collection, not a lazily-evaluated sequence. Also, the choice of anonymous delegate vs. lambda syntax is independent from LINQ, but I chose the older syntax in the non-LINQ example because that's what the C# language looked like back then, before version 3 and the introduction of LINQ.)

### When you have several rules:

Then you have to combine them in some way before you match `Foo` objects against it. That is, you need to decide whether a `Foo` must match all rules (logical AND), or at least one (logical OR), etc. You could derive combined rules from two given ones as follows:

```
static Func<Foo, bool> And(this Func<Foo, bool> ruleA, Func<Foo, bool> ruleB)
{
    return x => ruleA(x) && ruleB(x);
}

static Func<Foo, bool> Or(this Func<Foo, bool> ruleA, Func<Foo, bool> ruleB)
{
    return x => ruleA(x) || ruleB(x);
}

Func<Foo, bool> ruleA        = foo => foo.a == 2;
Func<Foo, bool> ruleB        = foo => foo.b == 12;
Func<Foo, bool> combinedRule = ruleA.And(ruleB);
```

Since you allow your users to define the rules, you probably don't want to hard-wire constants in such rules; so you could create factory methods (or classes), e.g.:

```
Func<Foo, bool> PropertyAEquals(int value)
{
    return foo => foo.a == value;
}

Func<Foo, bool> PropertyBEquals(int value)
{
    return foo => foo.b == value;
}
```

You can make this as flexible as you want. All you need is factory methods or classes that return `Func<Foo, bool>` and the logic necessary to translate user input from the UI into calls to the correct factory methods.

Comment: if I am not mistaken then building the someRule correctly will require a going back to reflections. Example if my next rule was only foo.a=1 then the only way to create the new rule (Func<Foo,bool>) is using reflection. Let me know if I am mistaken, been away from code a bit long.

Comment: @peeyushsingh: No, you don't need Reflection for any of this. I've expanded my answer a bit. Again, I strongly recommend that you study the [Specification pattern](http://martinfowler.com/apsupp/spec.pdf), it appears to be very appropriate here.

Answer (score 0):

```
 public bool AbidingByRule(Dictionary<string,object> rule)
         {
             var type=this.GetType();
             int unmatchedCount=rule.Count(r => !r.Value.Equals(type.GetProperty(r.Key).GetValue(this, null)));
             return unmatchedCount == 0;
         }
```

Comment: I think I have already mentioned that I am using reflection in the current solution

Comment: Also, comparing two item of type `object` with `!=` is not a good idea... It's better to use `object.Equals`

Answer (score 0):

You could use `NCalc` ([link](http://ncalc.codeplex.com/)) to parse simple expressions as rule, e.g. :

```
    class Foo
    {
        public int a { get; set; }
        public int b { get; set; }
        public int c { get; set; }
    }

    static bool VerifyRule(Foo obj, string rule)
    {
        NCalc.Expression expr = new NCalc.Expression(rule);
        expr.EvaluateParameter += (name, args) =>
        {
            args.Result = typeof(Foo).GetProperty(name).GetValue(obj, null);
        };
        return (bool)expr.Evaluate();
    }

    // USAGE EXAMPLE
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var foo1 = new Foo() { a = 3, b = 4, c = 12 };
        var foo2 = new Foo() { a = 1, b = 4, c = 12 };

        // verify rules
        var res1 = VerifyRule(foo1, "a == 3 && b == 4"); // returns true
        var res2 = VerifyRule(foo2, "a == 3 && b == 4"); // returns false

        // more complex rules:
        var res3 = VerifyRule(foo1, "(a < 4 && b > 5) || c == 12"); // returns true
        var res4 = VerifyRule(foo1, "a + b == 7"); // returns true
    }
```

**Note**:
I'm still using reflection here. In my opinion you can't avoid that since your rules are defined dynamically through the UI...